# Proof of Eichler-Shimura isomorphism

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms

For a congruence subgroup $\Gamma \subseteq \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ we have the *Eichler-Shimura isomorphism*
$$
M_k(\Gamma) \oplus \overline{S_k(\Gamma)} \cong H^1(\Gamma,V_k)
$$
with $V_k$ a certain $\Gamma$-module coming from a $(k-1)$-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. We have $V_2 \cong \mathbb{C}$ so that for $k=2$ the isomorphism reads:
$$
M_2(\Gamma) \oplus \overline{S_2(\Gamma)} \cong H^1(\Gamma,\mathbb{C}) = \operatorname{Hom}(\Gamma,\mathbb{C})
$$
My question concerns the prove of this isomorphism, in particular the special case $k=2$. As far as I know, a crucial step in the original proof is computing the dimensions of both sides and showing that they are equal. This confuses me, because I think that there should be a "geometric" proof, that moreover works in a much more general setting. I think so because group cohomology of $\Gamma$ is even *based* on the idea that it captures the cohomology of a certain space with fundamental group $\Gamma$. Let's focus on $k=2$. We simply need:

- the first cohomology of the open modular curve $Y_\Gamma$ is related to the left side of the equation, i.e., modular forms

  - this is indeed the case, as one can see modular forms as differentials on $Y_\Gamma$, which in turn live in the first (de Rham) cohomology group of $Y_\Gamma$
- the open modular curve $Y_\Gamma$ has fundamental group $\Gamma$

  - also this is true in nice situations, and generally it's quite close to true

Then by the basic principle/idea of group cohomology, this should give us a pretty straightforward proof of the isomorphism for $k=2$, no? And for $k > 2$, I've heard that there is also a correspondence between certain $\Gamma$-modules like $V_k$ and *local systems* on the modular curve. So in that case there should also be some *general* theorem relating group cohomology with sheaf cohomology with values in local systems, and then the Eichler-Shimura theorem should just be a special case of that general theorem, no?

Can anybody tell me if one can prove the isomorphism in the flavor I have sketched, and if yes, why nobody (as far as I've seen resources) does so?

Comment: There is a "highbrow" proof going via de Rham cohomology and the Berstein–Gelfand–Gelfand resolution of the de Rham complex; but applying it here would be a sledgehammer to crack a nut. If anything I'd say you are misidentifying where the real difficultly lies: the problem is not to identify group cohomology with local-system cohomology (which is easy), but to identify either of those things with a space of modular forms. (Notice that the sheaf $\omega^k$, whose $H^0$ is the space of modular forms, is *not* a local system.)

Comment: Taking $k = 2$, it is true that modular forms (or their complex conjugates) can be viewed as differentials on modular curves. However, there's a huge gap from saying "there is a map $M_2 \oplus \overline{S_2} \to H^1_{\mathrm{dR}}$" to saying "the map is an isomorphism"; it is utterly un-obvious a priori that it is either injective or surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much! For $k=2$, one can at least see $S_2 \oplus \overline{S_2} \cong H_{\mathrm{dR}}^1(X,\mathbb{C})$ via the Hodge/Dolbeault decomposition of dR-cohomology with complex coefficients. From there I thought one could show that removing the cusps $Y=X\setminus \{\text{cusps}\}$ adds Eisenstein series, which are meromorphic forms on $X$, holomorphic on $Y$ and with a pole of order $\leq 1$ at the cusps. I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_form) is what I need. Probably I'll see what's going on once I understand more co/homology theories and their interaction.

Comment: In order to prove the Eichler–Shimura isomorphism, you have to do some actual work at some point; it's not just formal definition-pushing. (Proving the Hodge decomposition of de Rham cohomology involves real work.)